# Create SSH tunnels using any software

Tags: networking, ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

Currently, we have a few labs where all instances are in private subnet except Bastion VM. So developers are supposed to create an SSH tunnel from their laptop to Bastion and create another tunnel from Bastion to some microservice, so they can access the UI.

The process looks like this:

```
ssh -i <key>.pem -L <port x>:localhost:<port x> user@<hostname of Bastion>
User logged in to Bastion VM.

ssh -i <key>.pem -L <port x>:<hostname of microservice>:<port of microservice> user@<hostname of microservice>
Now they are able to access UI at http://localhost:<port x>
```

Now, this is fairly complex/time-consuming task for everyday usage, so I was thinking of setting up software which can be configured to do the same at one click.

I found out [Secure Pipes](https://www.opoet.com/pyro/index.php), but not sure how to use it for my purpose. Can someone suggest an alternative to achieve the above using some other software?

Comment: What OS are your devs using?

Comment: Most developers are on macOS Mojave

Comment: Have a look at `ProxyCommand` in the ssh configuration file. In general, I write a small script file I just call for more complex tunnel setup. Also note you can repeat the `-L` option for several tunnels (one of my current scripts has about a dozen of them).

Comment: @grawity, that was a great answer, can you please repost it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complex because you're doing it in a complex way. OpenSSH already has mechanisms for simplifying this kind of frequent connections.  (**Note:** This post assumes that the developer has private keys for *both* connections on the local machine, i.e. the bastion host doesn't hold some uncopyable credentials.)

First find a way to compress it it down to one SSH command. This actually reverses the tunneling slightly, as the bastion host now relays the SSH connection and not the web connections.

```
ssh -i <key>.pem -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i <key>.pem -W %h:%p user@<bastion>" -L <portX>:<microservice>:<mport> user@<hostname>
```

In very recent OpenSSH versions, it can be simplified further using `-J` / `JumpHost` instead of manual ProxyCommand:

```
ssh -i <key>.pem -J user@<bastion> -L <portX>:<microservice>:<mport> user@<hostname>
```

Now convert this to ~/.ssh/config options – identify those which are needed for connecting to the bastion host itself, those which apply to the service hosts, and those which are common to all of them (the 'Host' sections accept multiple names and even wildcards):

```
Host <bastion>
    User <user>
    IdentityFile <key>.pem

Host <hostname>
    User <user>
    IdentityFile <key>.pem
    #JumpHost <bastion>
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p <bastion>
```

Having this in place (which can be centrally deployed), your command becomes just:

```
ssh -L <portX>:<microservice>:<mport> <hostname>
```

(There is also a way to automatically append the company domain, e.g. if the server is called svc1.dev.example.com, then either `Hostname %h.dev.example.com` or `CanonicalDomains dev.example.com` will let you run `ssh svc1`.)

That's about as simple as a generic method can get – the remaining four parameters are inherently variable (depending on each dev's needs), so even if you slap a graphical UI on top, the user will need to provide the same amount of information. (It works with OpenSSH on any OS.)

That said, if the *same* tunnels are established every time, they can also be coded in ~/.ssh/config (`-L` corresponds to LocalForward), and the dev only needs to run `ssh <hostname>`.

(Practically any OS capable of running OpenSSH also supports scripts, generally written in sh/bash, and/or command aliases.)